# How do I find unknown values of constants that make a function differentiable everywhere?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have this function, and I need to find the values of $a, b, c$ and $d$ so that $f(x)$ will be differentiable everywhere.

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
ax^2+b, & x<1 \\
cx+d, & 1\le x<3\\
(x-4)^2-1, & x\ge3
\end{cases}$$

What I've been trying to do is set several different limit expressions equal to each other, but I haven't been able to get anywhere with that. I've only been able to get one answer (which might be wrong):

$$\lim_{x\to 3^+} (x-4)^2-1=\lim_{x\to 3^-} cx+d$$
$$(3-4)^2-1=0$$
$$0=c(3)+d$$
$$-d=c(3)$$
and  then
$$\lim_{x\to 3^+} c(3)+d=\lim_{x\to 1^+} cx+d$$
$$\lim_{x\to 1^+} cx+d=\lim_{x\to1^-} ax^2+b$$

Am I heading in the right direction with this? Every time I set one equation equal to another I end up getting $0$ as my answer.

Comment: first apply continuity , then apply for  differentiability for the selected points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from continuity $$ a+b=c+d\\3c+d=(3-4)^2-1$$ now $$f'=\left\{\begin{matrix}
2ax & x<1\\ 
c & 1<x<3\\ 
2(x-4) & x>3
\end{matrix}\right. $$ and now $$lim_{x \rightarrow 1^{-}} f'=lim_{x \rightarrow 1^{+}} f'\\ \rightarrow2a(1)=c\\lim_{x \rightarrow 3^{-}} f'=lim_{x \rightarrow 3^{+}} f'\\ \rightarrow c=2(3-4)$$ you will find a,b,c,d by solving the system of equation $$ \left\{\begin{matrix}
c=-2\\ 
2a=c\\ 
a+b=c+d\\ 
3c+d=0
\end{matrix}\right.$$